# Expand texarea on focus and go back to previous on unfocus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a text area. Whenever someone will click on the text-area then the height will be increased and clicking again anywhere in the screen height will be decrease.

```
<textarea id="revbox" style="height: 50px; width: 260px;"></textarea>

<script>

    $('textarea#revbox').focus(function () {
    $('textarea#revbox').animate({ height: 150 }, 1000); 
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
```

But the code is not working. How can i do that?

Comment: missed the last line. sorry. edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is good for the `focus` event, and you only need to add similar code for the `blur` event. Try this:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="revbox" style="height: 50px; width: 260px;"></textarea>

<script>

    $('textarea#revbox').focus(function () {
        $('textarea#revbox').animate({ height: 150 }, 1000); 
    });

    $('textarea#revbox').blur(function () {
        $('textarea#revbox').animate({ height: 50 }, 1000); 
    });
</script>
```

Please note that you need to include jQuery at the top (preferably in the `<header>`).

Comment: Instead of including jQuery twice you should have fixed the order

Comment: @Andreas I did not include any jQuery. I selected jQuery in in snippet's drop-down and it added those lines. I have no idea why it added the two lines like that, but that's not part of the answer anyway.

Comment: But it is part of the problem, because @TanjimaTani includes the jQuery library **after** the expansion script. Your solution only works because the snippet generator adds the script tag at the top of the snippet.

Comment: @Andreas OK, I see your point now. I've fixed it and added a comment. Thank you for the note.

Answer (score 1):

try using `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="revbox" style="height: 50px; width: 260px;"></textarea>

<script>

    $('textarea#revbox').on("mouseenter",function () {
        $('textarea#revbox').animate({ height: 150 }, 1000); 
    });

    $('textarea#revbox').on("mouseleave",function () {
        $('textarea#revbox').animate({ height: 50 }, 1000); 
    });
</script>
```